# Azure Data Factory dynamic folder names using date formats

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm having an issue creating the syntax for a a wildcard path expression within my data flow.

We have data coming from a data lake container with a folder structure like the one below with the YYYY/MM/DD being dynamic:

`sensor/micActivatedEvent/YYYY/MM/DD/*`

I created the below expression but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to load the latest set of files for when the trigger runs the pipeline

`@concat(utcNow('yyyy'),'/',utcNow('MM'),'/',utcNow('dd'),'/*')`

Comment: Is this resolve your issue by using the sample code in [formatDateTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#complex-expression-example),

`@concat('Test_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy/MM/dd'))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by following the below format,

Use the `formatDateTime()` on `utcnow()` with the appropriate format that you need to show year, month and date.

***Example sample code:***

***Case 1:***

```cs
@concat('sensor/micActivatedEvent/', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy/MM/dd'))
```

***Case 2:***

Thanks to `@Himanshu` below is referred from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70a0dfb8-878c-4ea1-afa5-66aed5f59500/azure-data-factory-create-dynamic-sinkdestination-folder-structure?forum=AzureDataFactory#:%7E:text=Yes%20you%20can%20do%20that,%20please%20add%20the,%28utcnow%20%28%29,%27dd%27%29,%27/%27,formatDateTime%20%28utcnow%20%28%29,%27mm%27%29%29%20and%20it%20should%20work.).

```cs
@concat('sensor/micActivatedEvent','/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'))
```